# JNDI Path for JDBC data sources?

Tags: java, path, datasource, jndi

I sometimes see JDBC data sources specified in JNDI that use the "jdbc" path.  For example, the following (for Tomcat6):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myAppDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       ..... />
```

But then other times I see it without the "jdbc" in the JNDI path name.  Is using the "jdbc" just a convention?  Is it typical?  Where are these things documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just convention. You can call the resource whatever you like, but if you have many resources defined in your context, using a standard prefix makes it easier to identify what kind of resource it actually is.

In a similar fashion, a JavaBean resource would conventionally begin with `bean/` and a Mail resource would begin with `mail/`.

Comment: I also found this link which attempts to document them:  http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/namingconventions.html

Comment: That link doesn't exist any more.  The new URL is: [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html)